# Does Chrome on Linux not support alpha transparency in custom mouse cursor images?

Tags: css, linux, google-chrome, cursor, mouse

I am experimenting with creating a set of custom mouse cursors for a piece of web software. This is a purely aesthetic pursuit. Initially I was able to pull this off using the following:

```
.custom-cursor {
  cursor: url(assets/images/cursor-invert.png) 4 4, auto;
}
```

This works in almost all browser/OS combinations flawlessly, however a user has reported a strange issue. They are running Linux/Chrome56 (64-bit) and sent this screenshot:

[image: janky mouse]

How the mouse is supposed to look:

[image: not janky mouse]

The cursor is a PNG24 with alpha transparency, and it looks like the A channel is being flattened. I tried converting all my PNGs into `.cur` format (which seems to be more supported) and still the same result. Is this just a matter of the specific browser/OS combo not supporting alpha transparency in mouse cursors?

I can solve this by just using a format without alpha transparency, but it won't look nearly as awesome. Hoping there's a way to make this work.

**Edit**
Here is the cursor image I am using, for reference:
[image: custom cursor image]

Comment: What is the absolute URL for the cursor?

Comment: @repzero just added in the image for the cursor

Comment: I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ybn5aq78/) of your css, but it looks as expected under all browsers in 64 bit Debian (Firefox ESR 45.8.0, Chromium 57.0.2987.98, Konqueror 4.14.2, SeaMonkey 2.52a1 etc), so that's not it. Can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Or if not, a link to the site where this happens?